# Validate an XDR schema file itself

Tags: xml, validation, schema

How do I validate an XDR ([XML Data Reduced [Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDR_Schema)) schema file itself?

Note: I don't want to validate an XML file against an XDR schema, I want to check the correctness of the XDR. It must consist of a Schema root element, have AttributeType elements and so on.

It seems a DTD exists for the XDR definition. Where can I find the latest versin of it?

Answer (score 0):

Most XDR compilers have flag to only parse check your xdr file (semantic correctness of xdr rules). You should read documentation of your compiler.

Comment: Compiler? I use MSXML. Never heards that it could compiled XDR. Do you have a link to any XDR compiler?

Comment: I use rpcgen to generate *.cpp and *.h  files from *.x file.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things here. I'm talking about XDR as XML Data Reduced. You perhaps thought it was External Data Representation. I've changed the tags on my question. Sorry.